# How to call while loop from class?

Tags: php, pdo

I have class getinfo.php and script welcome.php. Inside get info class I have the function GetAll. I want to call all "first" by variable $this->first and is returning only one value, but I want all "first" in the row.Please see below

```
    //script getinfo.php
class GetInfo{
     function getAll(){
             global $conn;
            $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
            $sql->execute();
            while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $this->first = $row['first'];
            $this->last = $row['last'];
            $this->email = $row['email'];
            }

        }
}
        //script welcome.php

     <?php
      $info = new GetInfo();
      $info->getAll();
      echo $info->first;
      //this is returning only one value, but I want to get all row values.
      ?>
```

Comment: Why are you setting `$this->first`, etc.?  Why not just have `getAll()` *return* you an array of rows?

Comment: I want to use this function in different scripts and to call specific information's.Somewhere I want only "last" somewhere only "email" or all table values.

Comment: So, what's wrong with getting an array of all rows, but only using the value(s) you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make it list of array

```
    class GetInfo{
        function getAll(){
            global $conn;
            $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
            $sql->execute();
            while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $this->first[] = $row['first'];
                $this->last[] = $row['last'];
                $this->email[] = $row['email'];
            }
            return $this;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Your code:**

```
while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $this->first = $row['first'];
            $this->last = $row['last'];
            $this->email = $row['email'];
            }
```

is actually just setting `$this->first, $this->last,$this-email` to a new value for each row that is fetched from the database. Therefore only one value is "returned" when you're using $this->first.

*I'm not sure if I've understand you right (what you are trying to do), but if I did...*

You could use one function with an array as an argument that tells which columns you want to use, something like below:

```
//script getinfo.php
protected function getAll( $use_columns = array() ){
    global $conn;
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
    $sql->execute();

    $sql_arr = array();
    $row_index = 0;
        while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            foreach($use_columns as $uc) {
                $sql_arr[$row_index][$uc] = $row[$uc];
            }
            $row_index++;
        }    
    return $sql_arr;
}

 //script welcome.php

 <?php
  $info = new GetInfo();
  echo $info->getAll( array('first') ); //Print out all rows with first-value
  echo $info->getAll( array('last') ); //Print out all row with last-value
  echo $info->getAll( array('first', 'last') ); //Print out all row with first and last value
  ?>
```

> NOTE! I'm not sure above works to 100% (not tested), but I hope you understand the general idea!
>
> NOTE2! Be sure to validate values so user cannot put whatever value
>   into array argument that is sent to to the getAll function.